# MS-Access: Loop through code for each distinct value in a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table in my access database called Table_Example_1. Currently I have a loop that loops through an executes code based on the [Flag] field in my table, so if everything is set to 'Flag_1' it loops through these records and executes code to create a string output.

However there are some items that have the same flag for example 'Flag_1' but they need to be executed separately to the other records with the same value. I have added a field called [Grouped] and what I want to do is use this field to loop through everything in that grouping for the same flag.

So if there are 2 records set as Flag_1 and both are Group 1 these will run in the same loop. And records with Flag_1 in Group 2 will run in a separate loop. (The results of these will then be combined at the end)

My table with relevant data is below:

```
Business        Type            TableName   FieldName   Flag    Grouped
Red             Residential     RedTable    [Field_1]   Flag_1      1
Red             Residential     RedTable    [Field_1]   Flag_1      1
Red             Residential     RedTable    [Field_1]   Flag_1      1
Red             Residential     RedTable    [Field_2]   Flag_1      2
Red             Residential     RedTable    [Field_2]   Flag_1      2
```

My current code is below, this code currently only loops through records with the same Flag and does not take into account their grouping.

- It sets the record set and filters for everything with Flag_1
- It then loops through the record set and executes code to set the result variable.

So what I want to do to the below code is somehow add in a section that checks the grouping and looks through all groups and then my below loop will be nested in this.

I first need to get the distinct number of groups from the recordset. My example provided only has groups 1 and 2 but this will differ each time.

I then want to nest by below loop in this. I was thinking of using a for loop but I'm not sure how to check for the number of groups in the recordset and execute this for each of these groups.

```
 Public Function CreateFilterString(Business As String, Type As String, TableName As String)
        'Define variables
        Dim resultString_1 As String
        Dim resultStringFinal As String
        Dim recSet As Recordset
        
        'Flag_1 Related Flag RecordSet
        Set recSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table_Example_1 WHERE Table_Example_1.TableName = '" & TableName & "' AND Table_Example_1.Business = '" & Business & "' AND Table_Example_1.Type = '" & Type & "' AND Table_Example_1.Flag = 'Flag_1' ")
        
        'If there is no data in the recordset, then set the resultString_1 to blank
        If recSet.RecordCount = 0 Then
            resultString_1 = ""
        'Otherwise execut the following
        Else
            
            'If there is data in the recordset and the Flag field is Flag_1
            If recSet.RecordCount > 0 And recSet.Fields(7).Value = "Flag_1" Then
            
            'Set the resultString variable
            recSet.MoveFirst ' recSet now contains first record from the query
            While Not (recSet.EOF)
                'If it is the first case in the recordset
                If recSet.RecordCount = 1 Then
                    'code executed here that sets value of resultString_1
                Else
                    'code executed here that sets value of resultString_1
                End If
            'moves to next record
            recSet.MoveNext
            Wend 'end while
            
            recSet.Close 'close recordset when done
            
            'End of Flag_1 Related Flag
            End If
        End If
        
        'Set the result variable returned by the function
        CreateFilterString = resultStringFinal
        
        End Function
```

EDIT:
So to summarize and hopefully clarify what I want:

I want to be able to get the distinct values from the GROUPING field and then loop through each of these values.
I need a loop that runs through each unique value in the 'Grouped' field. So it will execute once for any record with a grouping of 1 and then reach the end of the loop and re-run for anything with a grouping of 2.

I understand that I can create a recordset using
`CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Grouped FROM Table_Example_1 WHERE ...` in order to get the unique values, but I don't know how to then use this information in order to create a loop to run through each value in the GROUPED field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could get the number of unique groups with `SELECT DISTINCT Grouped FROM Table_Example_1 WHERE ...` The number of different Groups would be `recSet.RecordCount`. I don't really understand, what you want to do with the information

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to get the distinct number of groups and loop through each of these values. I understand that I can create a recordset using SELECT DISTINCT Grouped FROM Table_Example_1 WHERE in order to get the unique values, but I don't know how to then use this info in order to create a loop to run through each value in the GROUPED field. But what I basically want is to create a loop that runs through each unique value in the 'Grouped' field. So it will run execute once for any record with a grouping of 1 and then reach the end and re-run for anything with a grouping of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you need two loops. One that will retrieve unique groups and one that will retrieve data for specific a group.

Something like this:

```
Public Sub T()
    On Error GoTo Trap
    
    Dim rGroup As DAO.Recordset, rData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim idx As Long
    
    'Get groups
    Set rGroup = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Grouped FROM Table", dbOpenSnapshot)
    If rGroup.EOF Then GoTo Leave
    With rGroup
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With
    
    'Loop through unique groups and get data for each group
    For idx = 1 To rGroup.RecordCount
        Set rData = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Grouped=" & rGroup![Grouped], dbOpenSnapshot)
        
        'Now the rData holds data specific to a group
        'Do more work
        
        rData.Close
        rGroup.MoveNext
    Next idx
    
Leave:
   If Not rData Is Nothing Then rData.Close
   If Not rGroup Is Nothing Then rGroup.Close
   Exit Sub
   
Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```